# Margin / Padding on mobile - Quasar Framework (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar, quasar-framework

How to use `spacing` when I want it to be responsive. 
For example, I wanna set marging`q-ma-md` , but I want it to be only when it's mobile phone. So how to do this?

In this style `q-ma-md` md means value of margin, not specifies screen width.

Comment: Did you check https://quasar-framework.org/components/spacing.html ? This official documentation says that `md` actually relates to the screen width.

Comment: I did. As I understood this param specifies value (how bit marging is)
Take a look at this screenshot please
https://imgur.com/CshaE4z

Comment: Well, if you really need different margins for different screen sizes, you could duplicate your container with the content. One container with small margins, one with big margins. Then you display or hide the whole container based on the screen size with the grid system.

Comment: it's a redundant hack. Given bootstrap has such features I thought quasar has the same, or kinda. 
Much easier is to add styles. But I bet smth like this exists in Quasar Framework. Just need to find it

Comment: Maybe this fits your needs? https://quasar-framework.org/components/other-helper-classes.html#Groups

Comment: Or you use gutters https://quasar-framework.org/components/flex-css.html#Using-Gutters

Comment: I read it. But it's still not clear for me. How to set marging only for mobile views.

Comment: Yes, is posible. Read the flex addons section: https://quasar-framework.org/components/spacing.html#Flex-Addons

It took me about 2 hours notice how this works:

q-{direction}-{bp}-{size}

The doc is pretty simple: 
- direction: similar to bootstrap: margin|padding top, right, etc
- bp: breakpoint: xs,md,lg,xl
- size: this was confusing at beginning: Quasar manage the SIZE in letters: xs, md, lg and xl, while bootstrap use numbers (0 to 5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quasar currently has this available similar to bootstrap and tailwind. From the [docs](https://quasar.dev/style/spacing#Flex-Addons)

> When enabled (**through quasar.conf.js > framework > cssAddon: true**) it provides breakpoint aware versions for all spacing related CSS classes.
> Note that there will be a noticeable bump in CSS footprint when enabling it. So only do it if you really need it.

> Usage: `.q-(p|m)(t|r|b|l|a|x|y)-<bp>-(none|auto|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)`

> Examples: `q-pa-xs-md q-pa-sm-sm q-px-md-lg q-py-md-md q-ma-md-sm`

Answer (score 1):

In your mounted function check the platform using

```
if(this.$q.platform.is.mobile){
this.class_variable='q-ma-md'
}
else{
this.class_variable=''
}
```

Then bind it on your frontend.

```
<div :class='class_variable'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will apply the class q-ma-md to the div if the device is mobile

```
<div :class="{ 'q-ma-md': $q.platform.is.mobile }"></div>
```